# PageId missing in SignedRequest in new C# SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am unable to get the page Id from Signed Request

I have tried 2 ways:
1. dynamic data = `FacebookWebContext.Current.SignedRequest.Data;`
  It will not contain any info about page
2. `Request.Params["signed_request"]`
  It return null value

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the user has connected with your application first?

An error message or more specific details about your method would be helpful to trouble shoot.